# ConnectException: Call From test/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I want to read a binary file in my hdfs. Hadoop services are up and running correctly. BUt it is howing this error. I have checked thoroughly that my hdfs port localhost:9000/.

```
sample_hdfs_path = "hdfs://localhost:9000/IOCL_DATA /DATA_2_18.12.2015_20.32.34.bin"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

bin_RDD = sc.binaryRecords(sample_hdfs_path,bit_lenght)
bin_RDD.take(1)[enter image description here][1]
```

After running this line, It always shows this. I think it's a connection problem but i am not able to rectify.

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-5fd499e19671> in <module>()
----> 1 bin_RDD.take(1)

/home/alethe/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1325         """
   1326         items = []
-> 1327         totalParts = self.getNumPartitions()
   1328         partsScanned = 0
   1329 

/home/alethe/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in getNumPartitions(self)
    389         2
    390         """
--> 391         return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
    392 
    393     def filter(self, f):

/home/alethe/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
home/alethe/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/alethe/Downloads/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o204.partitions.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From test/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000     
failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; 
For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

[image]

Comment: `For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused` .. Follow each step there

Comment: You might want to try `hdfs://test:9000`, if that is your hostname

Comment: @cricket_007 tried with test not working still.

Comment: Wondering if you able to run any other jobs on your cluster? It seems your node is try to connect to itself (127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000). In hadoop cluster, namenode try to connect to itself.  You need to setup password less  login  and /etc/host file with 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: @NaveenNelamali it's already password less login and we're running a single node cluster in the same machine.

Comment: Please show your hosts file. And show `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000`